# How to get the number of lines in txt file data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the data from a txt file and I wish to get the total row of the data.

Sample of TXT file:

```
    data1 content1 txt1
    data2 content2 txt2
    data3 content3 txt3
    data4 content4 txt4
    data5 content5 txt5
    ...
```

Sample of script file:

```
$.get(txtFile, function(data) {
var rows = data.split('\r\n');                       
$.each(rows, function(rowIndex, row) {
    var data = row.split('\t');
    var dataName = $.trim(data[0]).toLowerCase();
    // (more code)
}
```

I was wondering if there are ways to get the total row of the data in text file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: row.length gives me total length of a single row...but not total rows. In my example, I have 5 rows.

Comment: You may need to clarify the question... are you wanting the data of the text file, or the total number of rows in the text file, or some value from a specific row? Your title, description and code don't match.

Comment: @FlyingCat I said `rows`, not `row`.

Answer (score 1):

When your rows array only contains one element, I suspect the .split() did not match any text within your file. Maybe your lines do not end with \r\n?

```
var rows = data.split('\n');
```